# Is there any methodology to generate the non negative and non normal random data based on descriptive statistics of probability of lossing the game

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, simulation

I would like to generate non-negative random data (between 0 and 1) and non-normal. Is there any methodology to generate the random data based on the below distribution? Below are the descriptive statistics of the limited historical data of the probability of losing the game.

[image]

Since the distributions in the beta family take values in [0,1](based on Bruce Comment below), Can this be calibrated to beta distribution(to find parameters α and β) based on the historical mean and variance?

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @BruceET, I have edited my question and included a reference on beta distribution

Comment: Updated comment. Distributions in the [beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) family take values in $[0,1].$ And in R the function `rbeta` (with appropriate parameters) will take a random sample from a beta distribution. You can make guesses about $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from formulas for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ But it is unlikely you will find parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for a specific member of the beta family that come really close to matching the distribution that would have produced your sample. (You can get the sample size of the sample by comparing its SD and SE.)

Comment: For example, a huge sample with $\alpha = 2, \beta = 40$ gave about $\bar X = 0.05, S = 0.032.$